# If I am creating an online store and using the stripe api (for the first time) should I save credit card info in my database?

Tags: database, stripe-payments, credit-card

I am pretty sure doing so is a bad practice, but I just need to make sure that if I implement stripe, it will take care of all the data that the user will provide.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store credit card information in your database. Letting Stripe handle that is a must. Your server probably isn't PCI compliment and if your database is ever hacked you'd have a lot of problems.

Stripe has a few ways to collect payment details depending on how you want to set it up. First you could use [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial). Which is probably the easiest method but the least flexible in terms of design and customization. The second method is to use [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements). This provides more flexibility over the look and feel of the input fields and such.

Stripe also supports [iOS](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) and [Android](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) intergrations if you are looking for mobile support.

I highly suggest reading through the [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs) as it gives you a lot of useful and great information about how to handle many different use cases.

I should also mention that there was another way to collect payment details through Stripe but that looks to be deprecated now. I didn't realize that until now. But it looks to have been replaced by Stripe Elements. This method was called [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#collecting-card-details). I'm not sure if it still usable at this time since I never heard any updates from Stripe that they would stop supporting it. So as of writing this that might also be a solution. Probably not recommended tho.

The main point is to use one of the methods described above to ensure **NO** credit card data will ever hit your server.

Hope this helped!